# function using font lock functions requires restarting font lock mode

Tags: emacs, font-lock

I am confused about how font lock mode gets engaged. I do not have a statement that launches font lock mode in my `init.el`, but apparently it always runs as a minor mode. Furthermore I have the following function:

```
(defun testregexfunc ()
  (interactive)
  (make-variable-buffer-local 'font-lock-extra-managed-props)
  (add-to-list 'font-lock-extra-managed-props 'invisible)
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          '(("\\(\\[\\)\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\)\\(\\]\\)"
                             (1 '(face nil invisible t))
                             (3 '(face nil invisible t))))))
```

It uses font-lock specific things. But it only takes effect once I do `M-x testregexfunc` followed by `M-x font-lock-mode` twice. First time disables font lock mode second time starts it. But it is not running as a major mode now, as the buffer still displays whatever mode the buffer was in before. Okay, so I guess the function sets some values and only take effect once the mode restarts. I figured maybe I need to add a hook to font lock mode like this:

```
(add-hook
 'font-lock-mode
 'testregexfunc)
```

No... does not do anything. What do I need to do to not have to restart font lock mode for the function to work?

I got that function from here and modified it some. I don't understand most of its definition and the documentation on font lock does not really help me much:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/using-font-lock-regexp-groups

Comment: How about adding your font-lock function to major-mode hooks, rather than a font-lock-mode hook?

Comment: I tried that too, I still need to restart font lock mode then. I tried `(add-hook
 'haskell-mode 'testregexfunc)`, but same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the functions you are looking for are `font-lock-flush` and `font-lock-ensure` which together declare the buffer's font-locking out-of-date and then refontify it. So, you could alter your function as follows,

```
(defun testregexfunc (arg)
  "Fontify buffer with new rules. With prefix arg restore default fontification."
  (interactive "P")
  (if arg
      (font-lock-refresh-defaults)      ;restore the defaults for the buffer
    (make-variable-buffer-local 'font-lock-extra-managed-props)
    (add-to-list 'font-lock-extra-managed-props 'invisible)
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil ;make the "[" and "]" invisible
                            '(("\\(\\[\\)\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\)\\(\\]\\)"
                               (1 '(face nil invisible t))
                               (3 '(face nil invisible t)))))
    (font-lock-flush)                   ;declare the fontification out-of-date
    (font-lock-ensure)))                ;fontify the buffer using new rules
```

Comment: Okay thanks. This fixes the issue of manually restarting font lock mode. Can you still tell me what I need to do for this function to get executed once I engage a certain major mode? I still need to call the function manually, even though I have it put in a hook... for example for haskell mode.

Comment: A simple roundabout solution is define a minor mode and enable it in your major mode hook, eg. https://github.com/ludwigpacifici/modern-cpp-font-lock/blob/master/modern-cpp-font-lock.el#L329. Otherwise, I think you would need to modify the mode's fontification rules to avoid fontification happening twice. I'm not certain about that though, it would require delving deeper.

Comment: Also, if you want to permanently change the font-lock for a mode you use `font-lock-add-keywords 'mode` in your mode's config, no need to wrap it in a function